# Reorder array keys after unset element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
array (size=1)
  'images' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'image_name' => string 'image name' (length=10)
          'image__seo_name' => string 'image-name' (length=10)
          'image_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/folder/images/products/image.png' (length=45)
          'image_original_name' => string 'altinorfozotel7.png' (length=19)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'image_name' => string 'image name 2' (length=12)
          'image_seo_name' => string 'image-name-2' (length=12)
          'image_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/folder/images/products/image2.png' (length=46)
          'image_original_name' => string 'altinorfozotel3.png' (length=19)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'image_name' => string 'image name 3' (length=12)
          'image_seo_name' => string 'image-name-3' (length=12)
          'image_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/folder/images/products/image3.png' (length=46)
          'image_original_name' => string 'altinorfozotel4.png' (length=19)
```

I unset `array['images'][0]` key and need to reorder array keys in `array['images']` array

I tried to use `array_values($array['images'])` but 'images' array key changed to 0 index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array['images'] = array_values($array['images']);
```

should work

Comment: Here is my php code
$order = 1;
unset($arr['image'][$order]);
$arr['image'] = array_values($arr['image']); 
but unset is not working, its still same.